# Number of orientations of a regular $n$-simplex

Tags: graph-theory, simplex, polytopes, orientation

I am looking for the formula or sequence of values for the number of orientations of regular $n$-simplexes.

For orientation I mean a rotation such that the $n$-simplex is in the same previous position but with different facets/edges (for example, for the triangle, I can choose one of the 3 sides as base). Sorry for the not rigorous math language.

I have computed 1, 3, 12 for a 1-simplex, 2-simplex, 3-simplex respectively. I don't know if that is right, anyway I could not find anything suitable in OEIS or elsewhere.

Any hint?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're asking about the number of orientation-preserving rotations of an n-simplex?  Since for a 2-simplex, there are 6 if you can flip it over, too.  If you don't care about orientations, then there are $(n+1)!$ possibilities, since every vertex can be sent to any other vertex.  Divide by two to get the number of orientation-preserving ones.  (FYI: this group of symmetries is known as the "alternating group". https://oeis.org/A001710)

Comment: It's the same as the 24 rotational symmetries of a cube, right?

Comment: Indeed.  There is an abstract "simplex" whose "vertices" are the four diagonals of the cube, and every permutation of the "vertices" (i.e., the diagonals) can be realized by some rotation/reflection of the cube.

Comment: Thank you. Can we mathematically call the flip over of the $2$-simplex a reflection? And generally speaking for an $n$-simplex with vertices $(v_1, v_2, \ldots v_n)$ is it sufficient to replace $(v_1, v_2, \ldots v_n)$ with $(v_n, v_{n-1}, \ldots v_1)$ respectively to get the "flip over" and then apply a rotation to send every vertex to any other vertex?

Comment: Yes, that can be considered a reflection. The simplest reflection is from swapping two vertices, for example $(v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots,v_n)$ vs $(v_2,v_1,v_3,\dots,v_n)$. Every permutation of vertices is the result of a sequence of these simple types of reflections -- if the number of reflections is even the permutation is considered to be "orientation-preserving." A full "flip over" isn't always a reflection, like $(v_4,v_3,v_2,v_1)$ and $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ are just rotations of each other. This is controlled by whether or not a corresponding triangular number is even or odd. (The 4th, 6, is even.)

Comment: Thank you. I posted [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4236653/573047) to made more clear what I would like to do.