# Getting all permutations of vertices of a regular $n$-simplex through rotations (plus a reflection).

Tags: graph-theory, simplex, polytopes, orientation, permutation-matrices

Suppose that, starting from a regular $n$-simplex with vertices labeled with $(v_1, v_2, \ldots v_n)$ I want to obtain an arbitrary permutation of the vertices $(w_1, w_2, \ldots w_n)$ out of the $n!$ possible, is it enough to:

1. Rotate the $n$-simplex around its centroid till $w_i$ is in the position occupied by $v_i$, $i = 1, \ldots ,n$ in the original positioning of the $n$-simplex;
2. If step 1. is not enough, exchange $v_1$ and $v_2$ in the original positioning and then repeat step 1. till $w_1$ replaces $v_2$, $w_2$ replaces $v_1$, and $w_i$ is in the position occupied by $v_i$, $i = 3, \ldots ,n$ in the original orientation of the $n$-simplex;

Regarding the rotation about the centroid, for 2D it is clear, for 3D I mean any sequence of single rotations of any angle around whatever axis passing by the centroid. For 4D or more, something similar... What I mean is I can move the solid provided that its integrity is preserved and the centroid stay still. After comments and answers, a more formal way to say this is apply a rigid motion fixing the centroid, or apply an orientation preserving isometry of the ambient space fixing the centroid.

Is this feasible?

Comment: What do you mean by "rotate around its centroid"? In 2 dimensions, that would be clear and unambiguous. But how do you rotate, say, a 3D object about a point?

Comment: I have edited the question to explain what I mean for rotation of a 3D object. For 4D or more I need to formalize it... maybe with some help...

Comment: The formal way to say "move the solid provided that its integrity is preserved and the centroid stay still" is either "rigid motion fixing/preserving/about the centroid" or "orientation preserving isometry of the ambient space fixing/preserving/about the centroid"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *most* straightforward thing to do is a sequence of up to $\binom n2$ reflections.

Assuming a regular $n$-simplex, we can draw a hyperplane through $n-2$ of the points, passing through the midpoint of the edge between the remaining $2$ points, and perpendicular to that edge. A reflection through that hyperplane swaps those $2$ points while keeping the rest fixed.

Since we can generate any permutation by a sequence of swaps, we can permute the vertices however we like by a sequence of reflections.

Indirectly, this method also confirms that a plan like the one you describe also works. The composition of two reflections is a rotation (through the $(n-2)$-dimensional "axis" where the two hyperplanes intersect). In this case, all of the hyperplanes above pass through the centroid, so the "axes" will also contain the centroid.

So just take a sequence of reflections that gives you the permutation you want, then group them up into consecutive pairs. This will give you a sequence of rotations, possibly with one reflection left over.

(I should clarify that I mean a *simple* rotation here. In [4-dimensional space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space#Simple_rotations) is when this first matters: a "simple rotation" fixes a plane, and "double rotations" are weirder. For higher values of $n$, you get even more complexity, but the composition of two reflections is always a simple rotation.)

Comment: Thank you. I have asked another [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4236685/573047). The other answer seems negative though, for $n > 3$.

Answer (score 3):

If by

> Rotate the $n$-simplex around its centroid

You mean "apply an orientation preserving isometry fixing the centroid", then the answer is yes. One way to see this is that $S_n$ is isomorphic to the Coxeter group of type $A_{n-1}$. In particular it is generated by the reflections $s_1,\dots,s_{n-1}$ which algebraically correspond to the transpositions $s_i=(i\;i+1)$ for $1\le i\le n-1$, and geometrically correspond to the reflections of the $n$-simplex in the hyperplane containing the points $v_1,\dots,v_{i-1},v_{i+2}\dots v_n$ and the midpoint of the edge joining $v_i$ and $v_{i+1}$.

Now any permutation of the vertices can be achieved by an element of $S_n$, and eny element of $S_n$ can be written as a product $t_1\cdots t_k$ for $t_i\in\{s_1,\dots,s_{n-1}\}$. If $k$ is even this is a product of an even number of orientation reversing isometries (reflections), which is an orientation preserving isometry (case 1 in the question). If $k$ is odd, $t_1$ is a reflections, and $t_2\cdots t_k$ is an orientation preserving isometry (case 2 in the question).

Actually case 2 specifically askes that $t_1=s_1=(1\;2)$, to achieve this when $t_1\neq s_1$, pre-compose $t_1\cdots t_k$ by $s_1s_1$, the identity.

Note that in up to three dimensions, all orientation preserving isometries fixing a point are rotations about an axis (or the identity). In higher dimensions, there can be other orientation preserving isometries, so if specifically only *rotations* are allowed in higher dimensions, then the question is not possible.